# What is the origin of "nerp" or possibly "nurp"

Tags: etymology

In the 1970s I asked a clerk at the lumber yard in Laguna Beach, California, whether I could have a hole drilled in a door hinge so I could put a set-screw in it. That would prevent the removal of the hinge, an action which would permit a miscreant to open the door even though it was locked.The clerk said, "So you want to have it nerped?" I have not had occasion to learn whether that word is still in use... or its origin.

Comment: You have a great memory!

Comment: You took my comment. Anyway, VERY entertaining searching google for nerp :)

Answer (score 4):

The clerk was saying (most probably)  “So you want to have it *NRP'ed*?” rather than *nerped*.  A NRP hinge is a Non-Removable-Pin hinge ([1](http://www.boltonhardware.com/category/door-hardware/door-hinges/non-removable-pin-hinges/),[2](https://www.google.com/search?q=nrp+hinges&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=ur5kUpPMGan3igLNx4AQ&sqi=2&ved=0CDAQsAQ&biw=1016&bih=604)).  Some styles of NRP hinges use a setscrew against the pin; others use a swaged-in-place pin (effectively a rivet); and some have bolster pins that project from the face of a hinge leaf into the face of the other leaf.